# Posting to facebook pages with a native php app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook Native app using PHP SDK, so that I can automatically post links and events **to the pages** I own from cron service every now and then.

---

I got App Access Token, and gave this app all required privileges: publish_stream, manage_pages and create_event.

With Graph API I can post to my users profile page with simple call to:

```
$facebook->api( "/" . USER_ID . "/feed", 'post', $tmp_fields );
```

but I cannot post to a page with similar:

```
$facebook->api( "/" . PAGE_ID . "/feed", 'post', $tmp_fields );
```

Moreover I cannot get pages credentials with `/USER_ID/accounts` since it returns:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#15) This method is not supported for native apps",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 15
   }
}
```

nor access `/PAGE_ID/?fields=access_token` since it just returns id field of the page.

---

So, what is the right way of posting to users pages for standalone apps which can be for example run from cron every week or so. How to get Page Access Token from just App Access Token in a Native app?

Comment: I don’t think you understand what a “native” app is.

Comment: Without further explanation, your comment isn't really helpful...I want to create standalone app which will post to the wall of a facebook page. I might want to fire it by double clicking it's icon on a Desktop, or through cron/scheduler.

Comment: PHP isn’t the best choice for a native desktop app then. PHP is interpreted, it needs a server to be ran. Desktop apps are usually written in some derivative of C and then compiled into a program.

Comment: Again, if you cannot provide an answer, please don't comment.

If I change a language to C, how will I get another error then the given:
"This method is not supported for native apps" ?

Have you even read the question? It's not really that related to PHP as to Facebook API and how to post to page with a native app.

Comment: No one can provide an answer because you can’t make a native desktop app in PHP. And I dare say any one would think twice before _attempting_ to answer if you continue to be rude.

Comment: PHP is programming language which can be used for many things beyond programming web pages. It has bindings for many libraries, and you can make native applications which don't have anything to do with web server. Those can use GTK+ or QT bindings to build GUI, or be standalone TUI programs or whatever one chooses. Moreover, whatever language one uses is here completely irrelevant. This is Facebook API problem not the problem of the programming language in any way. If anyone knows the answer, please reply. I'm not going to continue to reply to Martin Bean, as he obviously doesn't know...

Answer (score 0):

Some methods of the Graph API are not available to desktop or mobile ("native") applications. A [related bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274826259306869) I found suggests that this is because desktop applications must store their app secret within their application (which could cause it to be decompiled and used to make malicious API calls).

If this Facebook application is for your own personal use, or if you are not embedding your App Secret within it, you could get around this limitation by changing your Facebook application's type to a web application in the "Advanced" section of the application's settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martey for a reply. I've used Web app type for other FB apps, but I consider that a hack, not a solution. Note that currently, with native app (!), I *can* post to users feed... The problem is that I cannot post to a pages feed the user owns, although I have right permissions. Therefore, I still don't know why native apps can post to users page(no need for web app type), but cannot post to pages feed the same user owns...

Comment: If you think that this is a bug, you should report it to Facebook. I think it is likely that this is "by design". Note that your issue is not that posting to a Page's feed fails, but that native applications are unable to access the "accounts" connection. I specifically references the bug about creating test users as it uses a similar API endpoint.